# Where to call my class from

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I have a program that uses the java swing jframe as my main class.

It passes the arguments to the jframe which then calls another method from its constructor called populate menus.

This then goes and reads the files that will make upthe menus.

My question is should I create and object that reads in all the files and pass that to my constructor?

Below is what I do now.

I seperate the arguments(these are the config file locations) and then I call the constructor of the jframe which i then pass the values.

```
public static void main(args[]){

final String isoconfig = args[0];
final String userlist = args[1];
final String equipment_list = args[2];
final String config = args[3];

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  try{
     new UserInterFace(isoconfig,userlist,equipment_list,config).setVisible     *     (true);;}
  catch(IOException ioe){
      System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());}}
       });}
}
```

Here is the constructor code

```
public UserInterFace(String isoList,String userList, String equipment_list, String config)throws IOException  {

   initComponents();
   populatemenus(isoList,userList,equipment_list,config);
   initObjects();}
```

What I was thinking was to do this

```
 public static void main(args[]){

 Readfiles configfiles = new Readfiles(args);  

 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      try{
          new UserInterFace(configfiles).setVisible(true);;}
      catch(IOException ioe){System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());}}
     });}}
```

Comment: How did all those * characters get into the source?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Congrats for reaching 70K rep points :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  Thanks.  Noticed you've cracked 20K.  Congrats back.  :)

Comment: @David Drennan for why reason is there main(arg...) two times, which one is proper, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable with hardcoded value as local variable for `FileIO`, `XxxStream` or `JDBC`, otherwise this questin isn't answerable at all ...

Comment: You don't need to use `invokeLater` here.  It is OK to manipulate with Swing objects outside GUI thread while they are not in visible hierarchy.

Comment: @Mikhail Vladimirov wrong suggestion ..........

Comment: It's a matter of choice. Although your 2nd block of code looks better because it's shorter, it does mean implementing the Readfiles class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, maybe it would be better to do just like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    new UserInterface (args).setVisible (true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail,Thanks but should I then call the reader that populates the UserInterface from its constructor?

Comment: Yes, constructor will hide all the complexity inside.